# KVM Hypercall Inovcation

Tags: communication, host, kvm

how would the guest OS invoke a hypercall from its user space such that it can be trapped by the host?

the hypercall API does not (at least for myself) give sufficient detail to be able to start using the registers for information passing to the host.

i would like specific code samples for how to do this with the register values that need to be set as well as how the trap can be caught and modified on the host side

*not the virtio_serial functions